# Confusion about using an old Xcode project in a newer xcode version and bulding for the store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I just finished developing a project  for IOS. My current Xcode version is 4.0.2 . And i'm targeting IOS 4.3.

My client only required for me to deliver the xcode proyect at the end so he could submit to the apple store himself.

Now he's claiming that he can't ship a product with the version of Xcode i'm using, that it only can be done using Xcode 4.5.2 !

1. Is he correct ?, I tried to find official info on that with no success. Now it's only posible to deliver with projects using the Xcode 4.5.2 version ? ( i would expected Apple to force to use a more recent xcode version, but the latest ?).
2. If so, can't he just use the project i delivered to him and just make the store build in his more recent XCode version ?, or do i need to upgrade to the latest xcode version ?
3. What's the minimum SDK target version being accepted by apple for submisions right now ?, i believed it was 4.3, but it's now an higher version ?
4. Assuming that my client is correct, it's currently impossible for a Snow leopard user to deliver builds to the store at all?, since the more recents Xcode Versions require the user to be in the Lion OS at minimum.
5. If i understand correctly Xcode version 4.5 removed support for building armv6 components, essentially forcing developers to drop support for iOS releases up through iOS 4.2.1, which if understand means no longer supporting 3G and older devices. Does this mean that the iPhone 3G, and first two generations of iPod touch are "deprecated" ?

Thanks for the understanding and the orientation.

Comment: You can test 1, 2, and 3 by seeing if your version of Application Loader errors out on submission.  The rest are a tentative Yes, and a definite Yes.